# Finding if string is substring of some string in python: a special case

Tags: python

I am working on finding if a string is sub-string of some string in `python`. It runs fine for all the cases but here is a special case where it fails:

In `python` shell I do:

```
x=repr('\r\r\r') 
y=repr('\r\r')
```

In this case `y in x` returns false. Can someone tell me what to do so that it returns true?

Comment: What a strange question. `repr('\r\r')` isn't a substring of `repr('\r\r\r')`, quite simply. Asking how to make it return true is like asking "how do I make 1+1 become 3?" Why did you expect it to be any other way?

Comment: You can use `x = r'\r\r\r'` and `y = r'\r\r'` if you want to compare the strings. Then `y in x` returns True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special case here. The reason this doesn't work is that `y` contains a leading and a trailing single quote:

```
>>> x=repr('\r\r\r')
>>> y=repr('\r\r')
>>> x
"'\\r\\r\\r'"
>>> y
"'\\r\\r'"
        ↑ This character is not in `x'
```

It's not entirely clear how you want this to work, but you *could* remove the quotes before testing the condition:

```
>>> y.strip("'")
'\\r\\r'
>>> y.strip("'") in x
True
```

This is probably a hack rather than a solution, but it's hard to propose a good solution without knowing the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks NPE. I thought it was behaving in a strange way becoz \r is carriage return(escape character). But you pointed out rightly that it is due  to the quotes accompanying the string y.